# iOS 8: setting view.layer.mask covers view, mask is top of UI hierarchy

Tags: ios, ios8, calayer, mask

My question is, how can I ensure that a view's layer.mask is at the back of the UI hierarchy, or, since that is not necessarily needed to accomplish the effect I'm going for, how can I put a border around a view which has rounded top corners and squared bottom corners on both iOS 7 and iOS 8? Below is the problem I'm running into with my current solution.

In iOS 7, when I set a view's layer's mask like so:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.view.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(WDFeedItemViewCornerRadius,
                                                                  WDFeedItemViewCornerRadius)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

The result is effectively a border around the view (the top part, by "Bruce Morgan" [which is a fake name just so you're not scared], has a border around it which is squared on the bottom and rounded at the top):

[image: iOS 7 with layer.mask]

However, running the same code on iOS 8 puts the mask IN FRONT of the view, like so:

[image: iOS 8 with layer.mask]

which is confirmed by viewing the UI Hierarchy (unfortunately, can't view the hierarchy for iOS 7):

[image: UI Hierarchy]

I've tried creating a view behind my current view for the sole purpose of applying a mask to it, as well as setting layer.zPosition to 0 and mask.zPosition to 0, but the mask STILL appears on top of everything. What's going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: All four of those items appear to have the same superview. Why not just set the `cornerRadius` on the superview's layer?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I need the bottom two corners to be squared, not rounded, but `cornerRadius` would round all the corners.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks to me like all four corners are rounded.

Comment: The top level view is actually a UITableView, and there are actually 3 UITableViewCells showing on this screen: one cell for 'Bruce Morgan' (which was being covered), one for 'Ronald Price,' and one for 'Maria Murphy.' So while it looks like it's all one view, it's actually 3, which is why I can't just round the corners.

Comment: Could they not al be contained within the same parent?

Comment: No, they couldn't be in the same parent unless I wanted to duplicate UITableView. There could be an arbitrary number of comments, and since I wouldn't want to create views for off screen comments, I'd have to reuse the views, which is exactly what UITableView does. Thus, it makes more sense to just use a UITableView, but that in turn means I can't put everything in one view: the post and each comment must be in their own subclasses of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeaaaaah... turns out a superview was calling `insertSubview:belowSubview:`, and for some reason (perhaps the 'belowSubview' argument wasn't done loading?), it just added the new view on top of all the others (in iOS 8, but not in iOS 7). Changing `insertSubview:belowSubview:` to `insertSubview:atIndex:` with index 0 solved the issue for me.